# jquery carousel active image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this plugin 
[webdesign-flash.ro](http://www.webdesign-flash.ro/p/u3dcar/index.html)
and i'm trying to zoom in or display larger the active image which is in front. there are no unique ids or classes used in this. but active image display the content (title). i tried to select active element by using following code. but doesn't seems to work.

```
jQuery(function($){

    if($("#fwdu3dcarDiv0-fluidwidth").find("p strong").length) {
      console.log("It exists!");
    }
    else {
      console.log("It doesn't exist");
    }

});
```

is there any way i can do this? just to display active image larger than others. 
Thanks!

Comment: are you getting any console using above code?
or are you able to assign IDs to particular Images or its parent DIVs?

Comment: no i'm not getting any console logs. also unable to assign ids to images. running on wordpress and only way to access by jquery.

Comment: are you able to provide Customizable  description text?
How did you provide it? is it `HTML` or Plain text?
Are you able to create a Plunker or Fiddle?

Comment: damn. i can add Customizable description text? thank you for coming up with that idea. now i'm gonna add a custom ID to paragraph element. let you know. many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, feeling Happy to Help. :)